# How could Satyaki have defeated Karna so many times?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, karna, satyaki

**Misconception about the help of divine chariot.** 
Since Karna fans like to cover up the facts and hide the true story about his defeats by saying that Satyaki had a special chariot given to him and a special driver like Daruka.

1. Satyaki only had that special chariot and Daruka for less than an hour during the Jayadratha-Vadha Parva for a short amount of time. He got it after he killed Bhurishravas and lost it after the end of the battle. Satyaki still yet defeated Karna many times.
2. Satyaki defeated Karna even during Karna Parva when Karna had Shalya as his charioteer.
   When Karna was made generalissimo of the Kaurava army still he was defeated by Satyaki.
   Satyaki defeated Karna during the day of Drona's death as well.
   Satyaki defeated Karna and his son Vrishasena before Karna killed Ghatotkaca too. 
   Satyaki even defeated Karna during the 12th day.
3. What excuses do Karna fans have for his above listed defeats at the hands of Satyaki then?
   Clearly in many conditions with or without a special chariot Satyaki still defeated Karna. 
   Karna also had a great driver like Shalya whose knowledge of horses was unmatched by anyone except for [Krishna's](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08031.htm):

> As that slayer of foes, viz., he of Dasharha's race, is acquainted
>   with horselore, even so is that mighty car-warrior, viz., Shalya
>   acquainted with horselore. There is **none equal to the chief of the
>   Madras in might of arm**s. As there is none equal to myself in weapons,
>   so there is **none equal to Shalya in knowledge of steeds**.

4. [On the 14th day a special chariot was provided for Karna in this as well](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07143.htm):

> A **new cat was brought for Karna** also, O king, unto which were yoked
>   four steeds of the best breed that were decked in trappings of gold
>   and white as conchs or milk. **Its kaksha and standard were made of
>   gold**. Furnished with banners and machines, **that foremost of cars had
>   an excellent driver**. And it was furnished with a profusion of weapons
>   of every kind. Mounting on that car, Karna also rushed against his
>   foes.

So Karna fans really cannot talk about having a special chariot. Also any advantage Satyaki's chariot gave him would be evening out the plainfield as the same day Karna received a backup team of warriors like Aswathama, Vrishasena, Kritavarman etc. So why is this a excuse for Karna's defeat?

5. Don't try to say that Karna was under the influence of Krishna's illusions. Krishna only stopped Karna from using his vasavi dart not anything else. And this illusion only affected Karna up until the 14th night.

During the 15th day their was no illusion yet Satyaki defeated Karna.

During the 16th day their were two times where Satyaki fought Karna. He defeated him the first time and proved to be a better warrior than karna in the second instance.

During the 17th day their were several times where Satyaki performed better than Karna (during their encounters). Here is a screenshot from Debroy's translation of BORI Mahabharata.[image: 17th day, last encounter of Satyaki & Karna]

Now for the question i wanna know how did Satyaki defeat a warrior like Karna? The same Karna that Bhishma labeled a Double Maharatha. The same warrior that Krishna offered everything. The same warrior who Krishna called superior to Arjuna.

Drona also defeated Satyaki, Burishravas defeated Satyaki, but the same Satyaki was able to defeat Karna countless times.[image]

Comment: Good question. I fail to understand the undeserved adulation this character gets!

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal, this is kali yuga.. people like to root for the 'bad-boys'

Comment: @ram the unfortunate truth of our times..

Comment: Generally many people take sides, and emotionally attach themselves to the characters. That's why some of these distortions come into existence. In fact Sri Vyasa himself says that after the tournament (when Karna first challenges Arjuna), some people dispersed praising Arjuna, some Karna, and some Duryodhana. I would assume that folks who refuse to see Karna's battlefield failures are mostly the ones who emotionally react to Karna's life and the way things happened for him. All these are emotional behaviour humans are prone to.

Comment: And by the way, I don't recall a place where Lord Krishna tells Arjuna that Karna is superior to him. There are two occasions that come to my mind -
1. Before the final battle between Arjuna and Karna, The Lord warns Arjuna. In that dialog The Lord says **perhaps** Karna is thy superior. That slokha is not an assertion by The Lord that Karna is superior. It reads like a cautionary advice warning Arjuna that he should assume Karna to be his superior and fight with full attention.

Comment: 2. After Gatotkacha was slain. In that night Lord Krishna says if Karna had his kavacha & kundalas that were naturally offered to him by The Sun God, he would have been invincible. The Lord says that even with his Chakra, and even with Arjuna's Gandiva, that armor would have been unbreakable. But this is not a testimony of Karna's superiority, as much as the superiority of the kavacha - it was divine like Arjuna's Gandiva, providing special advantages to the person using it.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question and seeing people who love to keep spreading anti pandava posts and love to keep glorifying karna by spreading fake stories i have decided to make an answer to this question.
The simple answer is that the reason Satyaki won so many times is because he was a better warrior than karna, a better archer than karna and many karna fans never decide to accept this.
What to speak of karna? Satyaki even defeated Bhishma.

- 1st defeat of Bhishma

  > Desiring to do that which would bring pleasure to Bhima, Satyaki used
  >   his arrows to swiftly bring down the aged Kuru’s charioteer. When his
  >   charioteer was killed, Bhishma, supreme among charioteers, was borne
  >   away from the field of battle by horses that were as fleet as the
  >   wind. O king! When the one who is great in his vows was thus carried
  >   away, Bhimasena blazed, like a fire consuming dry grass.

Analysis: Bhisma failed to reign over his horses so he was defeated by Satyaki. Bhisma as a great warrior should have been able to protect charioteer (driver) but could not, and thus he was forced to flee the battlefield. Fleeing is a defeat.

**Source**: Bhishma Parva Section 50

- 2nd defeat of Bhishma

> "At that instant, Satyaki, the brave descendant of the Shini lineage,
>   devoted to the truth, attacked the grandfather. He began to kill the
>   enemy with his firm bow and made the soldiers of your son tremble. He
>   was borne on silver steeds and unleashed arrows from his firm bow. O
>   descendant of the Bharata lineage! Among all those on your side, there
>   was no second one capable of withstanding him.176"

Analysis: Satyaki tooled Bhisma in this fight, Bhisma did not even fight back. And in the next line a demon known as "Alambusha" has to save him (Bhisma) from Satyaki.

Source: Bhishma Parva Section 59
Regarding Karna defeating Satyaki he only defeated Satyaki on the 17th day, before that Karna never ever defeated Satyaki in his entire life.
Even on the 16th day in Karna Parva when karna was the commander of the forces he ran away from Satyaki.

> At this, Karna, leaving Satyaki quickly pierced Arjuna with three
>   arrows and Krishna with twenty, and Partha again repeatedly. Although
>   many were the arrows that he shot while slaying his foes in that
>   battle, like Indra himself inspired with wrath, Karna yet felt no
>   fatigue. Meanwhile Satyaki, coming up, pierced Karna with nine and
>   ninety fierce arrows, and once more with a hundred.

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08030.htm

On the 17th day Satyaki defeated Karna again.

> Then Satyaki, of immeasurable soul, O Bharata, placing himself on the
>   side of Bhima's car, began to afflict Karna who was in front of Bhima.
>   Though exceedingly afflicted by Satyaki, Karna still approached Bhima.

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08051.htm
Not to mention all the times Satyaki defeated karna on the 12th day, 14th day etc. Satyaki even defeated karna on the 14th night (Ghatotkatcha's death day).

Also karna never fought Satyaki fairly, he did a group attack on Satyaki. Here is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Bhishma was not defeated, His charioteer was killed. That is it and other soldiers started to confront him so Bhishma was busy fighting those people

Comment: He can drive a chariot. He is Parashuramashishya

Answer (score 2):

## Satyaki vs Karna

Satyaki was a crook warrior who killed Bhurishrava through cheating with his guru Arjuna. What could Arjuna teach his disciple instead of cheating. I request everyone to read the war between Satyaki and Bhurishrava and then you will know that how brave was Satyaki. I am going to analyse the wars between Karna and Satyaki. You have neither given any link not chapter name about many wars but I found.

- **[12th day war](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07030.htm)**

Bhima, Satyaki and Drishtadyumna pierced Karna with 3 arrows. Karna cutoff their bows. Then they attacked Karna with darts but Karna destroyed them. Then Bhima, Satyaki and Drishtadyumna pierced Karna with arrows and his bow was cut down. Now how could it be a defeat? He was neither chariotless nor unconscious. He did not fled from the battle. Then how it is a defeat? Now some Karna haters strated saying that, Duryodhana and others came to rescue Karna. The line :- ***The King Duryodhana, Drona and Jayadrath rescued Karna from the Satyaki ocean as the former was about to sink into it.*** By quoting this line some people claim the defeat of Karna. But before deciding anything read next line also:-***Then Dhrishtadyumna, and Bhima and Subhadra's son, and Arjuna himself, and Nakula, and Sahadeva, began to protect Satyaki in that battle.*** So warriors of both side came to rescue their warrior. So rescuing doesn't mean that someone is defeated. So this war was a tie.

- **[14th day war](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07143.htm)**

Here Karna was only made chariotless. Making someone chariotless doesn't mean that it was a defeat. Satyaki was using Devine chariot here that's why his chariot couldn't be destroyed. Satyaki sparing Karna is an interpolation as per BORI CE. He only spared Kauravas.

[image]

- **14th Night**

Satyaki came in group to attack Karna. Karna attacked Satayki and Satyaki trembled. All warriors fled away from him.

[image: Group attack of Satayki]
[image]

- **15th day war**

Satyaki defeating all warriors is an interpolation as per BORI CE Karna pierced Satayki with arrows and later it is written that Satyaki roamed around the chariots of Kripa, Drona and Karna but nowhere it is written that he defeated them.
[image]

- **16th day war**

Satyaki did a group attack on Karna and all retreated(fled away). If you think that Satyaki defeated Karna on 16th day then read this.

[image: defeat of Satayki lol]

## Karna vs Satyaki on 17th day

You have written that Satyaki did better than Karna on 17th day. So I am going to give you a list of his defeats on 17th day against Karna.

- First defeat of Satayki in a group attack.

[image]

- Second defeat
  [image]
- Again Sataykai had to retreat in a group attack

[image]

Comment: @srimannarayanakv it's the problem. When I use the KMG people call it interpolation and recommend to use BORI. It is helpful to give correct information without interpolation. In question BORI is used. Do you have any problem with BORI? Tell me.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv no problem. It's okay.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - because he was a far better warrior than Karna.

***2 defeats of karna on the 16th day.***

- **1:**
  Karna, leaving Satyaki quickly pierced Arjuna with three arrows and Krishna with twenty, and Partha again repeatedly. Although many were the arrows that he shot while slaying his foes in that battle, like Indra himself inspired with wrath, Karna yet felt no fatigue. Meanwhile Satyaki, coming up, pierced Karna with nine and ninety fierce arrows, and once more with a hundred.
- **2:**
  Then the son of Surya, resembling the chief of the celestials himself in prowess and like unto the younger brother of Indra, struck that foremost one of Sini's race with shafts whose splendour resembled the rays of the Sun. That bull of Sini's race also, in that battle, then quickly shrouded that foremost of men, with his car and steeds and driver, with diverse kinds of shafts terrible as the poison of the snake. Then many Atirathas belonging to thy army, accompanied by elephants and cars and foot-soldiers, quickly approached that bull among car-warriors, Vasusena, when they beheld the latter deeply afflicted with the shafts of that foremost hero of Sini's race. That force, however, vast as the ocean, assailed by foes possessed of great quickness.

**[Karna Parva: Section 30](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08030.htm)**

***Points:***

1. Their was no illusion of Krishna.
2. Their was not a special chariot.
3. Their was no special driver like Daruka.
4. No curses either.
5. Still on equal footings Karna always loses.

Comment: Karna is such a terrible warrior that does nothing except cause his own side losses (e.g. once causing the loss Akshauhini of his own side by expending one of his divine weapons). I honestly don't know how so many people can't separate archery (Karna really is the best mortal archer) from warfare (which Karna completely sucks at in every other aspect) and conclude Karna is a good warrior. Like his entire plotline is a cautionary tale in thinking you can be good in practice, just because you can ace a few tests better than anyone else.

Comment: Like warfare isn't a way to show how good of a "hero" you can be. Concentrate on results people. There is no point in doing something epic with your side loses. I don't know why I have to explain this to people.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [FAQ Index for HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) and specifically [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: aupakarana ji - i agree with what you say about karna but the thing is popular fiction and biased fanbases have created a generation of people who claim karna is a good warrior, he was really inferior to most of the top tiers

Answer (score 1):

With the day 12, I do not consider it defeat, because apart from Satyaki, Dhrishtadyumna and Bhima were also fighting against Karna. Sure, some Kaurava warriors came to protect him but also Pandava warriors came to protect Satyaki, after that, that was the battle:

Radheya was about to be
submerged in the ocean that Satyaki represented. At this, Duryodhana, Drona and King
Jayadratha rescued him. Dhrishtadyumna, Bhima, Subhadra's son, Arjuna himself, Nakula
and Sahadeva began to protect Satyaki in that battle.
'"Thus the extremely terrible battle between those on your side and that of the enemy
raged It was destructive of all archers. They were prepared to give up their lives. Infantry,
chariots, elephants and horses fought with elephants, horses, chariots and infantry. Chariots
fought with elephants and infantry, chariots fought with infantry and chariots fought with
elephants Horses fought with horses, elephants with elephants and chariots with chariots.
Infantry was seen to be engaged with infantry. Thus did that extremely fierce battle continue
and it caused delight to flesh-eating creatures. Those great warriors were without fear and
this extended Yama's kingdom. Many men, rathas, horses and elephants were killed there by
elephants, rathas, horses and infantry. Elephants were killed by elephants, rathas by armed
rathas, horses by horses and large numbers of infantry by infantry. Elephants were slain by
rathas, giant horses by the best of elephants, men by horses and horses by the supreme of
rathas. Tongues were lolling out. Teeth and eyes were gouged out. Armor and ornaments
Were shattered. Destroyed, they fell down on the ground. There were many others who were
struck down by the best of warriors. They fell down on the ground with fearful visages. They
Were mangled and crushed by the feet of horses and elephants. They were severely hurt and
wounded by the wheels of chariots and hooves. It brought delight to carnivorous beasts, birds
and flesh-eaters. There was a terrible carnage of people there. Those extremely strong ones
they were angry Using the utmost of their energy, they sought to kill each other. When the
strength of both sides was severely diminished, they glanced towards each other, their bodies
drenched with blood. The sun was stationed above the mountain on which it sets. OR
descendant of the Bharata lineage! The armies retreated to their respective camps. "'

It was not known later what happened, most likely the Kaurava warriors (Karna, Drona, Duryodhana and Jayadratha) defeated the Pandava warriors (Satyaki, Bhima, Dhrishtadyumna, Arjuna, Nakula, Sahadeva and Abhimanyu), because many times Sanjaya skip the narrative in some fights, when they are great victories for the Pandavas narrates the whole fight while in a fight where a Pandava warrior achieved a great feat to his enemy, does not finish telling the fight. A clear example is Kritavarma, who on the 14th defeated many Pandava warriors but Sanjaya does not narrate it. He told me that several Pandava warriors attacked him in a group. Sanjaya did not finish telling the fight but none of them crossed the defense of Kritavarma , it is obvious that he defeated all of them.

Day 12: Karna, Jayadratha, Drona and Duryodhana> Arjuna, Bhima, Dhrishtadyumna, Satyaki, Nakuka, Sahadeva and Abhimanyu.

On the 14th, Satyaki simply destroyed his chariot, when Karna got another from Daruka's younger brother, he faced Satyaki but Sanjaya did not finish telling the fight:

"O great king! The best of chariots was also brought for Karna." There were well-trained horses that had a great speed and they were as white as conch shells or milk. "The harnesses were colorful and golden." The sides and standard were made There were many weapons and garments and there was a good charioteer, Ascending this chariot, Karna rushed against the enemy again.

Obviously, enemy refers to Satyaki, since there was no other Pandava warrior who was fighting against Karna. Sanjaya does not narrate again the fight between Karna and Satyaki, but if I narrate how Satyaki defeated Ashwatthama, Kritavarma, Dussasana and thousands of warriors. It is obvious that Karna defeated Satyaki, but Sanjaya does not narrate it again.

Day 14 = Karna> Satyaki (with chariot of Krishna and Daruka as charioteer)

On the 14th, I do not consider her the defeat of Karna and Vrishasena, Sanjaya does not finish her narration:

"On seeing that he was advancing, Radheya pierced him back with ten swift arrows, O great king! While all those brave ones looked on, Satyaki asked him to wait and not run away, and then pierced him with ten arrows. the powerful Satyaki and the great-souled Karna was terrible, like that between Bali and Vasava, with the slapping of his palms, Satyaki, bull among the kshatriyas, frightened all the kshatriyas and pierced the lotus-eyed Karna back. Making the earth tremble with the roar of his bow, the powerful are of a suta fought against Satyaki Karna pierced Shini's descendant back with hundreds of arrows-vipatha, karni, naracha, vatsadanta and kshurapra 190 In that way, Yuyudhana, foremost of rathas among the Vrishni lineage, showered down arrows on Karna The Karna's armored are 191 quickly pierced Satyaki from every direction with sharp ar The Lord Satyaki used his weapons to counter his weapons and those of Karna. I have angrily pierced Vrishasena between the breasts. O Lord of the earth! Pierced by that arrow, the valiant Vrishasena lost his senses. I have discarded his bow and fell down on his chariot. Karna thought that maharatha Vrishasena had been slain. He was tormented by sorrow on account of his son and afflicted Satyaki. Maharatha Yuyudhana was oppressed by Karna. But he repeatedly struck Karna back with many arrows and with force. I have pierced Karna with ten arrows and Vrishasena with seven. Satvata severed the bows and arm-guards of both. They 192 strung other bows that were capable of terrifying the enemy and pierced Yuyudhana from every direction with sharp arrows. That battle raged on and it was destructive of heroes. "

Sanjaya again, does not finish narrating the fight between Karna and Vrishasena vs Satyaki, but if he narrates how Satyaki killed his parshni, he cut his bows and left Vrishasena unconscious? Obviously, Karna and Vrishasena defeated Satyaki.

On that same night, Karna defeated Satyaki along with Dhrishtadyumna, Shikhandi, Yudhamanyu and Uttamaujas:

On seeing that Bhimasena's immensely strong are engaged with Alayudha, the mighty-armed Karna had attacked the Panchalas. He drew his signature bow all the way back and releasing arrows with drooping tufts, pierced Dhrishtadyumna and Shikhandi with ten arrows each. The supreme among rathas used other iron arrows and made Yudhamanyu, Uttamouja and Satyaki tremble. O Lord of Men! Both on the left and on the right, all their bows could be seen, drawn into circles as they fought. There was the twang of bowstrings, the slapping of palms and the clatter of chariot wheels. During the night, these sounds were tumultuous, like that of clouds at the end of the summer. O king! The battle was beautiful, as if between clouds. The twang of bowstrings and the clatter of wheels were the roar. The bows were drawn into circles. The standards were like peaks. The torrent of arrows was like rain. Vaikartana was like a mountain that did not tremble. I had the essence of a large mountain. Or Indra among men! In that battle, the scorcher of a large number of enemies repulsed that hail of arrows and it was wonderful. "

Night 14: Karna and Vrishasena> Satyaki.

Karna> Satyaki, Dhrishtadyumna, Shikhandi, Yudhamanyu and Uttamaujas.

On day 15, I admit that Satyaki defeated Karna along with Drona and Kripa:

Satyaki, for whom truth was his value, roamed around in the paths of the chariots and was within the reach of Drona, Karna and Kripa. On seeing this, the great-souled Vishvaksena 100 and Dhananjaya honored Varshneya 101 and applauded him, since the undecaying one had repulsed the divine weapons of all the warriors. Vishvaksena and Dhananjaya descended on the soldiers. Dhananjaya told Krishna, 'O Keshava! Behold. Satyaki, for whom truth is his value, and who is the extension of the Madhu lineage, is sporting around before the preceptor.

Day 15: Karna, Drona and Kripa

But what about that? Drona defeated Satyaki many other times, literally Drona's first combat as commander were many Pandava warriors including Satyaki and Arjuna, but Drona easily defeated them.

In Karna Parva, Satyaki all he did was run from Karna, Satyaki was faster than Usain Bolt in Karna Parva, in fact I have seen people say that Karna was a coward when fleeing from Gandharvas, Bhima and Abhimanyu, but Satyaki fled more times than Karna in Kurukshetra. Now, with that appointment, it was just like this:

"The bull among the Shini lineage used his sharp arrows to slice down the many arrows that Karna shot. I have struck Karna with sharp and iron arrows and pierced his eldest are 711 with eight arrows. Kripa, Bhoja, 712 your sons and Karna struck him back with sharp arrows. However, the supreme one among the Yadu lineage fought with them, like the guardians of the directions fighting with the lords of the daityas. His bow roared down extremely fierce arrows. Satyaki became invincible, like the midday sun in the autumn sky. Those rathas 713 armored themselves well and again attacked, desiring to protect the foremost one from the Shini lineage. The rathas from Panchala united in that great battle, like large numbers of Marut surrounding Shakra, when he was afflicting the enemy. An extremely terrible encounter commenced between them and those on your side who were engaged in your welfare. It was like an ancient one between gods and asuras and destroyed chariots, horses and elephants. Afflicted by many types of weapons, chariots, elephants, horses and foot soldiers wandered around. They struck each other and wavered. They uttered loud wails of lamentation and fell down, deprived of their lives."

Again, Sanjaya did not finish telling the fight. So he had to finish in the victory of Karna, Kritavarma, Vrishasena and Duryodhana brothers

Comment: Good job gabriel. You have successfully created a really fake story to excuse karna of his defeats.

Comment: On the 12th day karna vs satyaki happened, dhrishtadyumna and bhima started to focus on other warriors so Karna only had to deal with Satyaki. He lost fairly. Satyaki defeated Karna.

Comment: On the 14th day Satyaki did defeat Karna, karna was supported by Duryodhana, Duhsasana, Shivavatar Ashwathama, Kritavarma, Kripa, Shalya and Vrishasen. That is more of a advantage than a chariot and a charioteer.

Comment: Satyaki was at a disadvantage and won, karna lost on day 14. Regarding the 14th night it is a defeat. First of all Vrishasena saved karna from Satyaki, Satyaki defeated Vrishasena, karna thought his son died, still karna being beaten down by Satyaki.

Comment: Karna on the 14th night fled from Satyaki and asked DUryodhana to do a group attack on him and you defend a character like karna? During Karna Parva Satyaki defeated karna 3 more times you claim he ran away only because you cant get over the fact that karna lost.